# Android - passing intent when popping activity off stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

One of two ways the user can go back from an activity:

1)The "home/up" button on the action bar

2)The back button which pops the activity off the stack

I want to pass an arraylist when going back, I set it like this for the "home/up" button on the action bar:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                Intent retIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondaryActivity.class);
                retIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.GEN_MESSAGE,returnVal);
                startActivity(retIntent);
                return true;
    }
}
```

But this logic is not hit when the activity is popped off the stack. Where can I handle what happens when act is popped?

Thanks folks

Comment: I think you need R.id.home

Comment: where? I'm looking for the code that runs when the activity is popped off the stack

Comment: In the code you provided, try changing android.R.id.home to R.id.home.

Comment: Result is unchanged. I put this in the onOptionsItemSelected() (see edited post) which is not getting hit when the activity is getting popped

Comment: i think i see what you mean. Ok, keep it as android.R.id.home if that works for the home button. For the back button you should override onBackPressed() in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the line  `setResult(RESULT_OK,retIntent);`

In your second activity:

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("key", arrayName);
    Intent retIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondaryActivity.class);
    retIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.GEN_MESSAGE,returnVal);
    i.putExtras(b);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,retIntent);
    startActivity(retIntent);
```

In first Activity `onActivityResult`:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

get your array using `extras.getString("key"):`